# adding column to df that calculates count of different column using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column in a df. I want the new column to equal the count of the number rows of each unique `'mother_ID`, which is a different column in the df.

This is what I'm currently doing. It makes the new column but the new column is filled with 'NaN's.

```
df.columns = ['mother_ID', 'date_born', 'mother_mass_g', 'hatchling_masses_g'] 
df.to_numpy()
```

This is how the original df appears when I print it:

[image: how df appears when I print it]

```
count = df.groupby('mother_ID').hatchling_masses_g.count() 
df['count']= count
```

Pic below shows what I get when I print new df, although if I simply `print(count)` I get the correct counts for each `mother_ID` . Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does `df['count'] = df.groupby('mother_ID').hatchling_masses_g.transform('count')` work?

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! Thank you! I've never heard of that transform function before, but that'll be a good one for me to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby transform('count')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('mother_ID')['hatchling_masses_g'].transform('count')
```

---

Notice the difference between [`groupby count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`groupby tranform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) with `'count'`.

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mother_ID': np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], 10),
    'hatchling_masses_g': np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
})
```

```
  mother_ID  hatchling_masses_g
0         b                  63
1         a                  28
2         b                  31
3         b                  81
4         a                   8
5         a                  77
6         a                  16
7         b                  54
8         a                  81
9         a                  28
```

---

#### `groupby.count`

```
counts = df.groupby('mother_ID')['hatchling_masses_g'].count()
```

```
mother_ID
a    6
b    4
Name: hatchling_masses_g, dtype: int64
```

Notice how there are only 2 rows. When assigning back to the DataFrame there are 10 rows which means that pandas doesn't know how to align the data back. Which results in `NaN`s indicating missing data:

```
df['count'] = counts
```

```
  mother_ID  hatchling_masses_g  count
0         b                  63    NaN
1         a                  28    NaN
2         b                  31    NaN
3         b                  81    NaN
4         a                   8    NaN
5         a                  77    NaN
6         a                  16    NaN
7         b                  54    NaN
8         a                  81    NaN
9         a                  28    NaN
```

It's trying to find 'a' and 'b' in the index and since it cannot it fills with only `NaN` values.

---

#### `groupby.tranform('count')`

`transform`, on the other hand, will populate the entire group with the count:

```
counts = df.groupby('mother_ID')['hatchling_masses_g'].transform('count')
```

`counts`:

```
0    4
1    6
2    4
3    4
4    6
5    6
6    6
7    4
8    6
9    6
Name: hatchling_masses_g, dtype: int64
```

Notice 10 rows were created (one for every row in the DataFrame):

This assigns back to the dataframe nicely (since the indexes align):

```
df['count'] = counts
```

```
  mother_ID  hatchling_masses_g  count
0         b                  63      4
1         a                  28      6
2         b                  31      4
3         b                  81      4
4         a                   8      6
5         a                  77      6
6         a                  16      6
7         b                  54      4
8         a                  81      6
9         a                  28      6
```

---

If needed counts can be done via [`groupby count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html), then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) back to the DataFrame on the group key:

```
counts = df.groupby('mother_ID')['hatchling_masses_g'].count().rename('count')
df = df.join(counts, on='mother_ID')
```

`counts`:

```
mother_ID
a    6
b    4
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

`df`:

```
  mother_ID  hatchling_masses_g  count
0         b                  63      4
1         a                  28      6
2         b                  31      4
3         b                  81      4
4         a                   8      6
5         a                  77      6
6         a                  16      6
7         b                  54      4
8         a                  81      6
9         a                  28      6
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. I spent a little while trying to google a work around before posting here, but I hadn't seen that ```[groupby transform]``` work flow before. Makes a lot of sense. This will be really helpful to know in the future. Thanks!

Comment: +10 for the great explanation about `transform`