# I need to sum based on certain criteria. I believe I need to groupby but I get an error when applying the method

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table that has the following type of data.

| id | start_time | approach | movement | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Right | 2 |
| 2 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Northbound | Right | 2 |
| 3 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Eastbound | Right | 3 |
| 1 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Thru | 3 |
| 2 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Northbound | Thru | 6 |
| 3 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Eastbound | Thru | 7 |
| 1 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Southbound | Left | 4 |
| 2 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Northbound | Left | 8 |
| 3 | 11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM | Eastbound | Left | 9 |

It then repeats itself but the time moves up by 15 minutes.

I would like to create a table that sums the values of Right,Thru,Left by grouping the id, time, and approach together.

I tried the following code, but I get an error. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
df2['combinedValue'] =  df1.groupby(['id','approach','start_time'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the error message

Comment: Related issue with `count` vs `transform('count')` -> [adding column to df that calculates count of different column using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68171235/15497888)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) if you want to add a new column to your original dataframe.

```
df1['combinedValue'] =  df1.groupby(['id','approach','start_time'], as_index=False)['value'].transform("sum")
>>> df1
   id              start_time    approach movement  value  combinedValue
0   1  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Southbound    Right      2              9
1   2  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Northbound    Right      2             16
2   3  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM   Eastbound    Right      3             19
3   1  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Southbound     Thru      3              9
4   2  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Northbound     Thru      6             16
5   3  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM   Eastbound     Thru      7             19
6   1  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Southbound     Left      4              9
7   2  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM  Northbound     Left      8             16
8   3  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM   Eastbound     Left      9             19
```

Use `sum` without `transform` to give you one row for each unique combination of `['id','approach','start_time']`.

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['id','approach','start_time'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()

>>> df2
   id    approach              start_time  value
0   1  Southbound  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM      9
1   2  Northbound  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM     16
2   3   Eastbound  11/12/2020 12:00:00 AM     19
```